# What to do if someone on video chat needs medical help

Tags: emergency

I live in Iowa and I am talking to a person in Idaho (or anyone in a different state), and the person on the other end experiences a sudden illness and needs EMS, what is the best way to get services out to the person you are chatting with (assuming you know their address)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer for the US and Canada:

Call 911 and explain the situation. They will be able to either forward your call or give you a number to call faster than you can find it on your own. Dispatch centers contact each other all the time so they know in advance how to do so.

If that doesn't work for some reason, grab google and type in "[Somewhere] Idaho Police Department" and call them directly. Next attempt: Idaho State Police.

Rest of the world:

Call the local emergency number and do the same. For example, in most of Europe that would be 112.

Source: Me, 15 years of experience in EMS. Can't find a good source to reference.

Comment: When you say local you mean local to me or local to my friend?

Comment: @traisjames I'd imagine Carey means the emergency number in the part of the world they are in.  So for example 112 in their European Union and most other countries in Europe.

Comment: @traisjames I mean the emergency number you would call if **you** had an emergency, as YviDe said. They will be able to connect you to emergency services where your friend lives faster than you can find it on your own.